# Merge Local Branch with Remote Branch using Git in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, merge

I have just started working with Git using Android Studio and I am facing an issue.

I have below structure in Studio.

**Local branch :-**

a) Accounts

**Remote branches :-**

a) master
b) Accounts

**I wanted to merge my Accounts branch with Remote's master branch.**

So I committed and Pushed my Local Accounts branch to Remote.

But when I saw their was two branches at remote as mentioned above.

**I can merge two branches created locally by**

1) Checkout of the branch where I want to merge and

2) Selecting the merge option by selecting the branch I want to merge.

But when I want to merge my local branch to remote branches there is no direct checkout option for Remote branches.

So what should I do ?

I searched a lot but didn't found any help for my scenario.

Comment: @VonC I was not able to understand the concept but now I got your point and I am accepting your answer and giving the bounty as well to you bcoz you were the first one to give the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to create a local branch named after your remote branch, and create from said remote branch (that is from `origin/yourDestinationBranch`).
See "[Create branch from develop android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37845953/6309)".

Once you have a local branch matching the remote branch you want to merge to, you can do the merge locally, and then push said merge commit to the remote branch.

Note: if you want to merge `Account` to the remote `Account` branch, then a simple [`git pull` (from Android Studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30767032/6309) would be enough.

Comment: According to your second para, If I push the merged branch then on the server it creates another branch with that merged branch name.

Comment: And according to your last para, for merging my remote account branch (which is the latest one ) pulling my code from remote I need to have the remote branch selected in android studio, but there is no option for that.

Comment: First, what do you want to do? Which branch do you want to merge with which?

Comment: Currently I work on my local Accounts branch and whenever I am done I commit & push my code to the Accounts branch on the server.So mostly I want to merge my Remote Account branch with the remote Master branch.But Its ok if its the other way round bcoz I have the same code.

Comment: @AshishShukla So create a local master branch from the remote origin/master one, as I describe. Checkout that local master branch. Do the merge locally, then push.

Comment: If I do this way it is creating another branch on the remote instead of merging. Do I have to select something before pushing it on server so that it will merge on the master ?

Comment: @AshishShukla No it won't create another branch on remote. It will update origin/master.

Answer (score 1):

As I'm more familiar with git on the terminal, in your Android Studio terminal -

`git fetch`

`git checkout master`

`git merge Accounts`

And then push master to update your remote master branch.

To do the same on android studio, without the terminal:

1. Fetch: VCS > Git > Fetch
2. Checkout to master from under "remote branches" in lower right panel.
3. Merge with Accounts: VCS > Git > Merge > Choose 'Accounts' branch and complete merge.
4. Push the updated, merged branch: VCS > Git > Push

Comment: Hi Sup , thanks for replying but I am searching for some option in android studio.

Comment: Hi Ashish, I have updated the answer with android studio based actions. Let me know if you run into any issues.

Comment: Thanks your answer helped me.

Answer (score 0):

My understand, there are 2 ways:

1. Locally merge:

   `git checkout master
   git merge Accounts
   git push master`

   BTW, you can also use `git rebase`
2. Remote merge:
   `git push Accounts`
   Launch a pull request(from 'Accounts' to 'master'), master accept this pull request and merge.